# is there unix timestamp range function in PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql, constraint

I have a table that stored user subscribe information, now I want to add a constraint to make the user did not subscribe the product multiple times in the same peroid of time. What I am tried to do like this:

```
CREATE INDEX user_sub_exclusion_index ON user_sub USING GIST (
  user_id,
  tsrange(sub_start_time, sub_end_time)
);
```

and create constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE user_sub ADD CONSTRAINT user_sub_exclusion_constraint EXCLUDE USING GIST (
  user_id WITH =,
  tsrange(sub_start_time, sub_end_time) WITH &&
);
```

seems the tsrange need the timestamp data type. I have tried range function but did not work. what should I do to make the gist index work and did not change the data type? This is the table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_sub (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    app_id varchar NOT NULL,
    product_id int4 NOT NULL,
    iap_product_id varchar NOT NULL,
    created_time int8 NOT NULL,
    updated_time int8 NOT NULL,
    user_id int8 NOT NULL,
    sub_start_time int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    sub_end_time int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    enabled int2 NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    order_id varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_sub_new_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT user_sub_new_un UNIQUE (order_id)
);
```

I have tried the change the field to timestamptz and tweak the sql like this:

```
CREATE INDEX user_sub_exclusion_index ON user_sub USING GIST (
  user_id,
  tstzrange(sub_start, sub_end)
);
```

show error :

```
SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: data type bigint has no default operator class for access method "gist"
  Hint: You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

what should I do to add the constraint?

Comment: You will have to convert the dreaded unix epoch to a proper `timestamp` (or `timestamptz`) in order to be able to build a `tsrange` (or `tstzrange`)

Comment: [Related](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/)

Comment: I have read that post and I think the unix timestamp is better than timestamp, because the timetamp is hard to interop, you have to handle the timezone leap month leap year and so on. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Well, Postgres will handle all that for you if you are using `timestamptz`. But if you do want to use a `tsrange` you will have to convert that number to a proper timestamp at one point or another.

Comment: seems timestamptz still could not created the index.

Comment: I have to install the extension `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PostgreSQL does not include GiST operator classes for base types like `bigint`. You have to create a standard extension that provides the required operator classes:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

Then you can create your constraint.

Note that adding an exclusion constraint automatically creates a GiST index.